# How can I organize JSON data from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I can't figure out how to correctly organize the JSON data that is created from my pandas dataframe. This is my code:

```
with open (spreadsheetName, 'rb') as spreadsheet:
    newSheet = spreadsheet.read()

newSheet = pd.read_excel(newSheet)

exportSheet = newSheet.to_json('file.json', orient = 'index')
```

And I'd like for the JSON data to look something like

```
{
  "cars": [
     {
       "Model": "Camry",
       "Year": "2015"
     },

     {
       "Model": "Model S",
       "Year": "2018"
     }
   ]
}
```

But instead I'm getting a single line of JSON data from the code I have. Any ideas on how I can make it so that each row is a JSON 'object' with it's own keys and values from the column headers (like model and year)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an indent argument to desired value in `to_json` function.

```
exportSheet = newSheet.to_json('file.json', orient='index', indent=4)
```